# No room for iPhone4 launch images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm launching an app for iPhone only, which started as an "empty application". In the images.xcassets folder of my project, there was space to add two (and only two) launch images, with no reference to the size of the device. I took screenshots of my app in the simulator and dropped them in place like this

[image]

When I tried to validate the project I got this error message

> ```
> Your binary is not optimized for iPhone5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must
> ```
>
> include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under
>   UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to (320, 568).
>   Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your
>   bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your
>   launch images.

Thinking it might be a problem with my plist file, I took a look at the info plist files. In the file `MyAppName-Info.plist`, I added this property with the values from the erorr message (320, 568). Note, I couldn't find a property `UILaunchImages`which is why I selected `LaunchImage` for a property value

[image]

However, when i ran the validation again, I got the same error message. Can you explain what I might be doing wrong (is the problem with my plist or with the launch images I've added or not added)?

Comment: Usually you get warnings when you run your app. But, I surmise that the resolution of your launch images is a problem. Check [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html) to verify.

Comment: @raurora thanks, I need to provide images that are both 640 * 960 and 640 *1136. How can I do that if there's only room for two launch images in images.xcassets?

Comment: Tried to make things clear below. HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your current LaunchImage and create a new one.

Images.xcassets > Choose Editor > New Launch Image (by right click)

[image]

Drag the images to your project first and then substitute launch images for app icons. Refer to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html) for the correct sizes and specific details. You should be good (no warnings) when the images are added to the following -

[image]